# How to run program on ( ubuntu bash windows 10 ) from windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, taskscheduler

I need to execute task every 5 minute in ubuntu bash and I like to use windows task scheduler.
I don't know how to write a .bat file to start application in ubuntu bash.
I tested these and did not work.
    c:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -l [program_name args]

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do, could you explain more?

Comment: I need to schedule task in ubuntu bash with windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

can run command on ubuntu bash with add -c flag in args

```
c:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c <command>
```

and write it in .bat file and then add to windows task scheduler.

Comment: When I do this I get an 0x75 code in the results and the script isn't executed.

Comment: open cmd and try `bash.exe -c "echo hi"` to check everything working fine

Comment: It was the run when user not logged in problem. Thanks.