# How can I use Python to interact with the Ubuntu terminal for windows 10?

Tags: windows, python-3.6, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running compiled c code on the Ubuntu subsystem for Windows. I would like to automate this process with a Python script that can open the terminal, send and read commands as well as closing the window.

I am trying this on Python 3.6 in Windows 10. I thought it was going to be the same as interfacing Python with the CMD but all the things I try are not yielding results. I want to know if anyone has tried to automate processes with the Ubuntu subsystem for Windows and how can that be achieved.
First, I had to find the .exe that launches the Ubuntu app, since it's downloaded from the microsoft store.

Using OS simply gives me the following result without opening the terminal.

```py
import os
os.system(r"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2019.521.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\Ubuntu.exe")
```

`1`

Also using subprocess will open the terminal. But parting from there, how can I give it commands and read the outputs?

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2019.521.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\Ubuntu.exe"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few things worth mentioning here.

Firstly, I don't think you need to use Python at all. If you want to schedule your compiled C code to run at a particular time (or linked to some other condition etc.), you can do all of this within WSL. I would suggest using `cron` which already comes with Ubuntu. It's a scheduling daemon that can execute tasks at specified intervals.

Secondly, if you want or need to use Python to achieve this (for whatever reason), I suggest you install a second version of Python within WSL. This will allow you to easily run whatever shell commands you want e.g. to execute your compiled C code. You don't need to worry about opening an Ubuntu window and then closing it etc. Personally I would actually go further and say that you should ditch your Windows 10 Python and just go with the WSL Python - it makes a lot of things much easier, especially if you're already familiar with Linux or are using WSL a lot for other tasks anyway.

Lastly, if you still really need to automate this from Windows 10, I suggest you use the Windows Task Scheduler to schedule a `.bat` file which opens bash (WSL) and executes a command as per the following link:

[How to run program on ( ubuntu bash windows 10 ) from windows task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818696/how-to-run-program-on-ubuntu-bash-windows-10-from-windows-task-scheduler)

(or if you don't need to schedule it, you can instead just execute the command from Python)

Hope that helps!